# Iterating through a file using a While loop instead of For

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Python 3 and want to turn something into a while loop but I am new so I am having some trouble with this.

```
username_chosen = input("Enter the username of the user for their details :")
with open("data.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if username_chosen in line:
            print(line)
```

The loop I want is where the program keeps checking if there is a username as the one entered by the user and if there is not then it tells them error and prompts them to input again until the program can find the username.

Comment: Your question is so basic, I could not find a suitable duplicate target. That's a sign that you should be _reading the documentation_ first before asking these kinds of questions.

Comment: The SO habit is to close as "too broad" when OP has simply failed in due diligence of research -- such as consulting documentation or on-line tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Not the exact answer you are looking for, but I think recursion is a cooler/more elegant way to solve this problem. Look at this:

```
def look_for_username(f):
    username_chosen = input("Enter the username of the user for their 
        details: ")

    for line in f:
        if username_chosen in line:
            print(line + '\nSUCCESS!')
            return

    print('No such username in file')
    f.seek(0)
    return look_for_username(f)


with open('user_data.txt', 'rt') as file:
    look_for_username(file)
```

So if `username_chosen` is not in `line`, then we move back to the first line of the file using `f.seek(0)`, and then we simply call `look_for_username` again. The only problem with using recursion like this is that python will only let you input 999 incorrect usernames.

Answer (score -1):

I'm surprised nobody's suggested:

```
with open("data.txt") as f:
    lines = tuple(line.strip() for line in f) #strip() the newline at the end of each line

while True:
    username_chosen = input("Enter the username of the user for their details :")

    #This condition will do what you have right now.
    if any((username_chosen in line) for line in lines):
    #The following will require the username to exactly match one of the lines in the file
    #if username_chosen in lines:
        break

    print("Invalid username") #Error message
```

Yes, if you have a large number of usernames then this is memory-inefficient. One of the other answers is probably your best option in that case.

Yes, I preserved the OP's username-checking algorithm, which, as some have pointed out, is flawed. If you don't want that, uncomment the other if statement.